# Exclude comments and strings while refactoring with Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Rename Method re-factoring not only rename the variables but anywhere including comments (it can not be sure if string in comments is really variable name).

For example:

```java
class ABC{
   private String username;

   private void X(){
    String str = "username";
   }
}
```

Now, after renaming the class member `username`, Android Studio will Behave like:

```java
class ABC{
   private String mUsername;

   private void X(){
    String str = "mUsername"; // it should be remain same as String str = "username";
   }
}
```

Is there any way to change the Re-factoring Setting in Android Studio?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After a struggle, i got the solution.
During re-factoring/renaming the variable/member, it will display a popup. In this popup, you will see a sentence

> "Press Shift+F6 to show dialog with more options"

Now if you will press "Shift+F6", a dialog will open for Re-factor-Setting.

Here, un-check `"Search in comments and strings"` .. Thats it..

Thanks for replies..

Comment: Good catch! Can't they just add an option for setting this for all future refactors? *sigh*...

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the link [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/refactoring.html):

**Renaming of packages, classes, methods, fields, method parameters and
local variables with reference correction**

> The renaming functionality
>   allows you to rename any package, class, method or variable and
>   automatically finds and corrects all references to it. Before
>   renaming, you can preview all references in a convenient tree-view,
>   where you have an opportunity to select usages/references to be
>   renamed. For any item being refactored, it is also possible to search
>   for its name occurrences in strings and comments, so that the
>   commented code is also changed and kept up-to-date. The Rename
>   refactoring can be invoked from any view (Project, Source, Commander
>   and Structure), as well as directly from the editor.

Answer (score 0):

In my version of Android Studio (2.2 RC 2) when I highlight a variable, right click and choose :

```
Refactor > Rename
```

this option pops up, then you can edit the `rating` text to whatever you want :

[image]

`Rename code occurrences` : it renames all usages of the variable named `rating`, throughout my project.

`Rename all ocurrences` : it renames the word rating (code, comments etc) throughout my project.